# Cambiar el color de un botón, dinámicamente, con esquinas curvas, sin perder la forma

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

Tengo un botón de login que debe cambiar de color según el colegio que haya elegido el usuario.

Yo traigo los colegios y sus respectivos colores mediante un servicio así que debo preparar mis editText y botones del login para que cambien de color cuando el usuario elija un colegio.

El problema es que mi botón de Logear está con esquinas curvas y deshabitado cuando no ha completado los campos de usuario y contraseña. El drawable que uso para lograr esa curva es este

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorButtonDisabled"/>
</shape>
```

y cuando ya ingreso todos los campos debo pintarlo del color del colegio que guardé en Shared Preferences

`btnLogin.setBackgroundColor(preferences.color)`

Lo malo es que pierde la forma y se vuelve rectangular.

Pude crear otro drawable con un diferente color para cambiar el color, pero no puedo hacer que adopte el color que traigo de mi servicio.

Existe alguna forma de lograr esto?

Comment: quiza podrias usar btnLogin.setBackgroundResource(preferences.color)

Comment: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xfff58827´
Me aparece este error. Es que Preferences.color es un Int, no un recurso

Comment: no es mas facil usar un putExtra para llevar los datos desde el colegio seleccionado a la pantalla de login ?

Comment: Claro, pero la pregunta es saber si se puede hacer lo del cambio de color sin perder la forma curva

Comment: Mire estos ejemplos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666660/8933039 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/42684952/8933039 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/24498041/8933039, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44542109/8933039, quizas le den alguna idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear el shape en el runtime. Ejemplo:

```
        GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
        shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);        // shape de tipo rectangulo en este caso
        shape.setCornerRadii(new float[]{20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0});    //con bordes superiores redondeados
        shape.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tu_color_1));      //aquí asignas el color de la forma
        shape.setStroke(3, getResources().getColor(R.color.tu_color_2));  //puedes agregarle un stroke
        String colegio;
```

El color lo puedes cambiar con if/else

```
   if (colegio.equals("colegio1")) {
        shape.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tu_color_3)); // configuras el color

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=16) {           // seteas así para api mayor a 16
            tuBoton.setBackground(shape);       // asignas el shape al botón
        } else {
            tuBoton.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);   // para APIs 15 o menos
        }

    } else if (colegio.equals("colegio2")) {
        ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Si me ayudó bastante. Ahora lo que tengo que hacer es poner un ripie jaja, pero ya con esto estoy mejor encaminado

Answer (score 0):

no es que pierda su estilo lo que sucede es que el BackgroundColor se superpone en el Drawable, y es por eso que pareciera que pierde las curvas, una solución rápida que se me ocurre y tal ves no sea la mejor es asignar el recurso manualmente, lo malo es que tendrías que hacer uno por cada color diferente que tengas.

// Claro que tienes que hacer la logica para saber que recurso drawable poner en que momento.

```
boton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_boton);
boton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_boton2);
boton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_boton3);
```

etc.

Saludos.

Comment: Eso pensé, pero mi plataforma va a estar añadiendo más colegios a lo largo del tiempo y con esto siempre tendría que estar añadiéndolo manualmente. Igualmente gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que aplicar un `Tinte` al fondo para que no pierda los diferentes estados el botón.

Para ello tenemos los siguientes métodos.

- [setBackgroundTintList()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html?hl=es#setBackgroundTintList(android.view.View,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)) .Aplicable desde la **API 21**.
- [setSupportBackgroundTintList()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/TintableBackgroundView.html?hl=es#setSupportBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas información la puedes encontrar [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638873/android-setbackgroundtintlist-on-pre-lollipop-devices/33640551).