# Cambiar los colores de un EditText dentro de un TextInputLayout, dinámicamente, mediante código

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

Tengo un EditText que debe cambiar de color según el colegio que haya elegido el usuario.

Yo traigo los colegios y sus respectivos colores mediante un servicio así que debo preparar mis editText y botones para que cambien de color cuando el usuario elija un colegio.

El problema es que no puedo pintar completamente el editText. Solo se pinta la linea, pero no el label(hint) aparte cuando no lo selecciono se pinta ligeramente la linea cuando debería ser gris.

[image: Login]

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Las funciones que usé son `user.backgroundTintList` | `user.setHintTextColor` | `user.textColor` y ni una me funcionó, al menos no el resultado que esperaba.

Anteriormente hice una pregunta similar, pero con un botón.

[Cambiar el color de un botón, dinámicamente, con esquinas curvas, sin perder la forma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158753/cambiar-el-color-de-un-bot%C3%B3n-din%C3%A1micamente-con-esquinas-curvas-sin-perder-la)

Comment: Te refieres a cambiar de color el fondo del EditText desde código?

Comment: El color del label y la linea. Si el colegio tiene un color verde entonces la linea debe ser verde cuando la seleccione y también el label (usuario y contraseña)

Comment: @SebastianPeredoMurga Ha probado: `android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"` ?

Comment: Si, pero no quiero hacerlo desde xml. Debo hacerlo en mi activity porque no se que colegio elegirán.